# $.clone and .cloneNode

Tags: jquery, clone, clonenode

I am a bit confused on the difference between jQuery `$.clone` and the raw `.cloneNode` property.

If I am doing

`$('blah').cloneNode(true)` this will create a global object outside of the jQuery space.

If I use

`$('blah').clone(true)` this will create a jQuery object inside the jQuery space but copy everything including events ?

If I am using jQuery should I stick with `.clone` and if I change my code from `.cloneNode` will there any effect ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A few things. You call `cloneNode` on `this` not `$(this)`. Second, with `cloneNode` you can't clone the events associated with the original node, whereas with jQuery's `clone`, it clones the events *and* data (if the first flag is set). Setting the second flag of `clone` clones the original element's children and *their* elements.

Use accordingly, according to your needs.

Comment: To answer your first question, yes it will copy events, but not the children or their events.

Comment: And to answer your second question, yes, I'd use `clone` if jQuery was the library primarily used. But it's a matter of preference, and you'll still have to append each new node back into a containing element using either cloning method.

Comment: Finally, if you're looking for good reference material, here's jQuery's `clone`:
[http://api.jquery.com/clone/](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

And here's the DOM's `cloneNode`:
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.cloneNode)

Comment: Doesn't Jquery's clone() call cloneNode()?  I thought I saw that while looking through the code once...